# Octopress preview with local mathjax?

Tags: mathjax, octopress, offline-mode

I often write posts with limited or no connectivity, which is one reason octopress is so appealing: it makes it really natural to write and preview posts offline. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make MathJax play ball. I have it set up and working properly using the CDN, which is how the static pages get uploaded to the server. But what I want is to be able to use a local mathjax to preview the posts offline. This I do not know how to achieve.

To be sure, I can change the `source/_includes/custom/head.html` point it to `./mathjax/MathJax.js`, but that only works if after `rake generate` I do `cp /path/to/mathjax public/`. But then I have to do this after *every* site (re-)generation, which is... cumbersome, to put it mildly. I've tried symbolic links, relative and absolute paths, but to no avail. Is there a better alternative?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the `MathJax.js`, you can put that in `source/javascripts/`. Doing so will add that file to the Octopress site which in turn means it'll be added to your site every time it's regenerated. source is the base of the Jekyll site Octopress has, so put everything in there except plugins and sass files.